# Determine Type PGP/SMIME/PEM and operation SIGNATURE/ENCRYPTION of an input file Java

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, openpgp, smime

I have to produce a function that take a signed or crypted input file and determine if it's PGP,SMIME or PEM file and return if it's crypted or signed.
so the return should be for example 'PGP-SIGNED' or 'SMIME-CRYPTED'

I'm reading the first line of the file to see if it contains BEGIN PGP so it's a PGP File
or Only BEGIN => pem
or contains smime

after, to determine which operation  Signature/Encryption :

**for PGP**:

I call

```
PGPObjectFactory factory = new PGPObjectFactory (inputFile  ,new BcKeyFingerPrintCalculator());
Object o = factory.nextObject();
```

and depending on the type of the o object I can say if it's encryption or signature.

**For smime**:

I check the smime.getContentType()

I don't know how to check the operation for pem file.

Is there a proper way using bouncycastle java to do these controls?

Comment: PEM isn't one format, it's a whole range of them; see RFC 7468. _If_ it's PKCS7 or CMS, which would be a logical possibility under these circumstancs but you don't give specific info to determine, see section 8 and 9. bcpkix contains PEMParser from which you get ContentInfo and can then check getContentType().

Comment: Thank you for your reponse.I'm looking to determine the format of the file and the operation (signature/encryption) that was done in it.  for example i have myFunction that take an inputstream and return a string. the input stream is a file signed or crypted with a specific format. and the return is a string with the form  FORMAT-OPERATION (ex : PGP-ENCRYPTED) now myFunction is devided in two part first is to determine format by reading the first line and the second step depends on the format i do some operation to know if it's encryption or signature. is there a proper way to do that ?